# Yii2 converting a normal query into eloquent

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to write this in Yii2 using `Query Builder`?

```
SELECT * FROM `report_details` order by `report_id` <> 5, reference_no
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are new to YII2 framework then this link will help you.
http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show report_id at top and then same reference_no record, you can use direct sql using UNION. If ReportDetails is the model name:

```
$reportId = 2;
$referenceNo = 5;

$sql = sprintf("
select * from report_details where report_id = %d
union distinct 
select * from report_details where reference_no = %d
", $reportId, $referenceNo);

$rows = ReportDetails::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

Check this sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7cb6/2

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i want to show only the same reference number. But i want to put the selected report_id on top.

Comment: Thank you sir! This is what im looking for.